# Image classifier without softmax

Tags: softmax, turi

I'm using Turi Create to generate a Core ML image classifier like this:

```
import turicreate as tc
data =  tc.SFrame('data.sframe')
model = tc.image_classifier.create(data, target='label')
model.export_coreml('classifier.mlmodel')
```

However, the model gives me softmax confidence values and in my application, I need pre-softmax values (I'll calculate softmax in the app). Is there a way to turn off the softmax layer?

I've had models like this supplied to me in the past, but now I need to generate my own. I've read through the docs and looked through source code (which I'm willing to modify if needed), but I don't know enough about machine learning to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can access attributes of the models. It means features, coefficients etc.

[Turi Documentation](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/blob/master/userguide/supervised-learning/linear-regression.md#linregr-model-access)

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks, but no I don't see how this helps me export a Core ML image classifier that that will output the confidence values I need.